# What is a semantically correct HTML element for a "statusbar"?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I am writing a simple webapp and I need a status bar. Something that updates often to reflect what JavaScript is doing. It will only contain text, short complete sentences, but in the future it might have small informational images. Like, "An error occured" or "Please wait, loading..." or "Player 2 has disconnected". Now, **I know how to make one**, but my question is:

What is the most **semantically** correct HTML element to use for this?

Or will I have to resort to a `<div>` or `<span>`? If so, which one? I generally avoid those because they seem like a last resort.

Also, the statusbar may be anywhere on the page. Don't base your answer on its location on the page, that's not what semantics is about.

Please support your answer with some sort of official resource (w3, anything) if you can.

Comment: I would say if you are putting the status bar at the bottom of the page (as is common with Windows apps), the `<footer>` tag is the most appropriate.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Nope, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) says: "The <header> element should be used as a container for introductory content or set of navigational links".

Comment: @Charlie74 At present, yes, it's at the bottom of the page. But that's not what semantically correct means. It should have the same *meaning* wherever it is.

Comment: **NEVER** ***EVER*** use w3schools... see http://w3fools.com. w3schools is ***NOT*** a good resource and should be avoided at all costs. I mentioned `header` because I thought it was stuck to the top. If it could be anywhere, then there's not really an HTML5 semantic element for that....

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow LOL that's just plain wrong.   There is a lot of useful information on that site.   There is NO useful information on w3fools, no references as to what is wrong with w3schools, just a bunch of "accusations".   It's a reference, one of many...  and generally a pretty good one.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow However, I do get a laugh at the occasional plug here for w3fools, so thanks for that little chuckle :)

Comment: @Charlie74 oh charlie charlie charlie...

Comment: @Charlie74 All I see are assertions without any data....

Comment: for the record: say on a rough estimate that w3schools **is** ~30% inaccurate (provides bad examples, poor practices, anti-patterns) and 70% useful content... then I argue that it is **only** a valid resource for the already seasoned professional and not a useful learning tool for anyone trying to learn the language.  What is to stop the *newbie* from knowing the 30% from the 70%? they have to accept that it is all good and that is how we end up with bad code infesting more sites. (just my 2 cents)

Comment: Also, if you're arguing against w3fools, you're arguing against Paul Irish: https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools

Comment: In an effort not to derail the OPs question with an argument about the validity of w3schools and the silliness of w3fools, I will bow out of this thread.   And Paul Irish?   Never heard of him.

Comment: @Charlie74 Really. You think there's "useful information" [here](http://w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp)? Or [here](http://w3schools.com/html/html_editors.asp)? Come on, anyone who's done even the tiniest bit of web development should know that's some of the worst "tutorial advice" on the web...

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 @DoorknobofSnow @Charlie74 @rlemon Stop it with the w3schools debate. I know that it's sometimes inaccurate but I am also not a newbie either. I just picked the first Google search result for `<header> html el` **so I could have a source to cite**, not because I don't know what it means. And this isn't about w3schools anyway. Sick of that debate and don't want it here. Shame on those who upvoted those comments. To cite the hover text for upvoting, "this comment adds something useful to the post". No, it doesn't.

Comment: @rvighne I recommend that, when you search for things on html5, you do a search like `html5 doctor header`. html5doctor is a great web constantly updated about html5. However I couldn't find anything related to your question, nor there nor anywhere else.

Comment: Apparently someone answered this question but deleted their answer. Is there any way to read a deleted answer?

Comment: @rvighne if you can figure out who posted the answer, you can go to their answers page on their profile and see recently deleted answers

Comment: Maybe having a lot of reputation and/or being a moderator. However it was probably deleted for good reason.

Comment: @Markasoftware Alright. I'll keep waiting then.

Comment: @rvighne the deleted answer is irrelevant (I see it, trust me). this question is doomed to be closed. just use a div..

Comment: @AlienArrays I don't understand why I'd use a wrapper. I'm talking about *semantics*.

Comment: @rlemon Why's it doomed to be closed? I think it's a perfectly valid question for the tags I chose (which are already on SO btw).

Comment: the deleted answer is: "If you're doing html5, there's an easy answer: the progress bar element.

If you're not using html5, then you can take your pick of all the many elements that were never designed to be progress bars."

Comment: @Markasoftware No you can't, you can only see *your* recently deleted answers.... You can however see deleted answers with 10k rep or more.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Why was this declared opinion-based? I mean, there are specifications for this sort of thing. I hope you're not doing that based on the w3schools debate in the comment thread -- that's just some people choosing the wrong place to argue.

Comment: Because some people might say header, some might say section, done footer, etc., and there is no one right answer.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow You're right, none of `header`, `section`, and `footer` are the right answer. There will always be wrong answers. But why is that a reason to close?

Comment: Because you could argue that any of them are "right," and there is not **one correct answer.**

Comment: Please add 1) the HTML version, and 2) example content which the statusbar may contain (is it only a loading icon; is it a short message like "Loading comments", …?).  Furthermore, it is my opinion that this question should be **reopened**. Such questions are not opinion-based! **Either** there are appropriate elements **or** not (which defaults to `div`) -- both cases make valid answers.

Comment: @unor I completely agree! That's exactly what I tried to argue to one of the closers.

Comment: @unor Edited to say what type of info can appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being unable to find any source of information, I'll answer all by myself and defend my position. My answer is: it depends. The direct answer to your question is that there's no element specific for the status.

However, when this happen the solution normally chosen is to use a generic element as `<div>` or `<span>` and assign it some semantics. This can be achieved with `class` and `id`, as you are well aware. We cannot expect html to be perfectly semantic and cover every case possible. They are trying their best to cover the most common uses.

A very similar case is the [`<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element). It was really common to see `<div class = "nav">` or similar code in old html. w3 realized of this and changed it to make it more semantic. Maybe/hopefully they'll do the same for all those `class = "status"` for a `<status>`, it just hasn't happened yet.

For solving your problem right now: I'd recommend using a `<p class = "status">` actually if your code is going to contain only a paragraph, as it seems. It's slightly more semantic than `<div>` and `<span>`.

Comment: Alright, accepting. I went ahead with a `<div>` temporarily, but the `p` option looks interesting.